# Knockout.Mapping - how to unmap when I've used a custom mapping?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I use the `knockout.mapping` plugin like so to not have to get a [moment](http://momentjs.com/) object instead of the crappy Date:

```
var mappedPeople = ko.mapping.fromJS(people, {
    Birthdate: {
        create: function(op) {
            return ko.observable( moment( new Date(op.data) ) );
        }
    }
});
```

Cool.

Now, after making modifications I want to return the entire array to regular js. Sounds like a job for `ko.mapping.toJS`!

But how do I go back to the date? `toJS` seems to take an options object but I can't seem to find an option that helps for this.

**Update**: I'm aware that in the specific scenario of using moment.js there are ways to get around this issue by coercing to string and re-wrapping, the underlying question is about how to provide custom "unmapping" functions to the plugin.

**Update 2**: Here is a jsbin demonstrating the issue: http://jsbin.com/uzesag/1/

Comment: It would help to see a bit more code. Could you extend it a bit to make a working example? The toJS method you mention seems like a fine choice, why is it not working?

Comment: can you post example of what you get and what you want to get?

Comment: @Jeroen here you guys go: http://jsbin.com/uzesag/1/

Comment: In general, you do custom unmapping by calling ko.mapping.visitModel(root, callback). But in your particular the issue is that your moment object has a number of properties and methods derived from the library. And even more methods are added via the Moment prototype. All these extra properties are being traversed as a part you your model by ko.mapping.visitModel. So I'd suggest only having JSON-compatible primitives in your view model

Comment: Hmm sounds like a pretty big limitation. Pull request time!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not strictly speaking answering the question of how to customise the unmapping itself, but I find a useful way of handling this type of situation is to wrap the original data in observables, but add computed observables (sub-observables) to the observables themselves. Best illustrated with an example ...

[JSBin showing moment added as sub-observable on Birthdate](https://jsbin.com/nuzuxa/edit?html,js,output)

The key snippet is here ...

```
    var mappedPeople = ko.mapping.fromJS(people, {
      Birthdate: {
          create: function(op) {

              var observable = ko.observable(op.data);

              // Attach computed to 'Birthdate' that produces moment
              observable.moment = ko.computed({
                read: function() {
                  return moment( new Date(observable()) );
                },
                write: function(val) {
                  observable(val.toDate().toISOString());
                }
              });

              return observable;      
          }
      }
  });
```

This means when you call ko.mapping.toJS or ko.mapping.toJSON, the original structure is preserved. The trick is that you actually need to store the moment back to the computed (to cause it to sync with the original data wrapped in observable) ...

```
function VM() {
  this.mapped = mappedPeople;

  // read moment computed
  var moment = this.mapped()[0].Birthdate.moment();

  // manipulate
  moment.add(5, 'y');

  // set it back
  this.mapped()[0].Birthdate.moment(moment);

  // unmapping 
  this.unmapped = ko.mapping.toJSON(this.mapped);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```